# Can't find my wordpress site when using www

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

If I do `example.com` my site is there, but when adding `www.` or `http://www.` I get the error message: server DNS address could not be found.

I'm pointing my domain to EC2 on Amazon Web Services.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a CNAME record for the www subdomain pointing at your EC2 Ip and also I recommend you to make a permanent redirect on your virtual host config file of your web server (apache for example) to redirect http://myexample.com to http://www.myexample.com. If you do not prefer making a permanent redirect you need to include www.myexample.com in your virtual host file as an alias.

Comment: I think its /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

Do you have CNAME DNS records set for `www` on GoDaddy? Try set `www` to `@` under DNS Settings CNAME. Read support article [here](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/add-a-cname-record-19236)

Comment: No, I didn't. I just did it know. So Host: www.example.com Points to: example.com, right?

Comment: Host: www Points to: @. Because @ represents the domain itself (example.com)